# Is it possible to increase container size only for reducer tasks?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

My use case is running Hive with Tez.

We normally use the following Hive setting to increase container memory:-

```
--e.g.
SET hive.tez.container.size=6656;
SET hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx8192m;
```

But what if I don't want this memory increase for containers to be applied for mappers, when I know my bottleneck is reducers -- can I exclusively increase container memory for reducer tasks alone?